# Show $n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is decreasing for $n \ge 3$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to show $\displaystyle n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is decreasing for $n \ge 3$ ?

Comment: Do you mean, that $n^{1/n}$ decreases as $n$ increases ?

Comment: yes as $n$ goes to infinity

Comment: When is a curve decreasing? When its derivative is negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}} \leq n^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

$$\iff (n+1)^{n} \leq n^{n+1}$$

$$\iff (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n} \leq n$$
and
$$(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\frac{1}{n^k} \leq \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} \leq e < 3$$

Comment: Interesting that there is no explanation of the equations in the final line. The first inequality in the final line doesn't exactly spring off the page.

Comment: @SuzuHirose it's more or less direct. Write all the factorial explicitly to see why

Comment: It's interesting that the elementary steps at the top are done explicitly and the final line is condensed.

Comment: @SuzuHirose But you understand it, right? :)

Answer (score 2):

$n^{1/n}=e^{\frac{1}n\ln(n)}$ and $\exp$ is increasing hence you only need to prove that $\frac{\ln(x)}x$ is decreasing for $x\ge3$, which should be easy :)

(if you still can't do it, tell me)

Comment: Maybe we could introduce the words "analytic continuation" here to make it clear what this action is.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = x^{\frac{1}{x}} \to \ln f(x) = \dfrac{\ln x}{x} \to \dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \dfrac{1-\ln^2 x}{x^2} < 0$ when $x > 3$. Since $n > 3$, $f'(n) < 0$, and this means $n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ decreases.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{d}{dn}[n^{\frac{1}{n}}]$

$=\dfrac{d}{dn}[e^{\frac{log(n)}{n}}]$

$=n^{1/n-2}(1-log(n))$
We want to prove that for all $n \ge 3, \frac{d}{dn}[f(n)]<0$.

For all $n>e, f'(n)< 0   $ because $(1-log(n))<0$, and all exponentials are positive.

Clearly $3>e$, so this statement is always true.

Comment: What does $\frac{d}{dx}$ mean in this context?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dn}$ you mean?

Comment: Well, usually $n$ denotes a “discrete variable”. But it's not necessary so; yes, it should be $\frac{d}{dn}$.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but $n>e$ so $$n^{1/n} > e^{1/n}>1 + 1/n = \frac{n+1}{n} \implies n^{1+1/n}>n+1 \implies n^{1/n} > (n+1)^{1/n+1}$$

Comment: better write $1/n+1$ as $1/(n+1)$ or $\frac{1}{n+1}$