# Supremum and infimum for $n^{1/n}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have the set $A=\{\sqrt[n]{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. I can see that $\inf A$ is $1$ as $\sqrt[1]{1}=1$ but I am having trouble with $\sup A$. I know that it is $\sqrt[3]{3}$ because it only decreases from then onwards. But I have trouble *proving* that is $\sqrt[3]{3}$. I have tried induction but I can't get it to work. Any strategies appreciated.

Comment: The derivative is $x^{1/x-2}(1-\log x)$, so $x^{1/x}$ has a global maximum at $x=e$. Then it decreases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the ratio
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}}{\frac{n^{n-1}}{(n-1)^n}}
&=\frac{\left(n^2-1\right)^n}{n^{2n}}\tag{1a}\\
&=\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)^n\tag{1b}\\[12pt]
&\lt1\tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$
Inequality $(1)$ means that $\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}$ is decreasing.

---

When $n=3$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}
&=\frac{64}{81}\tag{2a}\\[6pt]
&\lt1\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, for $n\ge3$, we have
$$
(n+1)^{\frac1{n+1}}\lt n^{\frac1n}\tag3
$$

---

When $n=2$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}
&=\frac98\tag{4a}\\[6pt]
&\gt1\tag{4b}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, for $n\le2$, we have
$$
(n+1)^{\frac1{n+1}}\gt n^{\frac1n}\tag5
$$

---

Inequalities $(3)$ and $(5)$ show that $n^{\frac1n}$ is greatest when $n=3$.

Comment: Part of this answer was previously given in [$(5)$-$(7)$ of this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4796676).

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of $f(x)=x^{1/x}$ is equal to $x^{1/x-2}(1-\log x)$. It is negative when $0<x<e$ and positive when $x>0$. It is $0$ if $x=e$. So $x=e$ is the global maximum. It means that we only need to check $n=2$ and $3$. Since $\sqrt[3]3>\sqrt 2$, we have that $$\sup A = \sqrt[3]3.$$